# How to validate multiple texts on a page in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to validate multiple texts on a web page. When I use the invoke method it is giving me 'Maximum call stack size exceeded error' because of multiple function calls.

How can I limit the use of .then() calls?

Below is my cypress code and I have more than 25 text validations to do

```
Cypress._.times(5, () => {
Elements.flow.gettablerow().eq(Elements.getrandomnumber()).within($row => {
    Elements.flow.getcheckbox().check({ force: true })
    Elements.flow.getbutton().click().then($el => {
        Elements.flow.getheader().invoke('text').then($text => {
            expect($text).to.equals('header text')
        })
        Elements.flow.getwarningtext().invoke('text').then(text => {
            expect(text).to.equals('warning text')
        })
        Elements.flow.getvelocitytext().invoke('text').then($text => {
            expect($text).to.equals(`velocit text`)
        })
    })
})
```

})

Comment: One of your `Elements.flow` methods has recursion. Can you post it?

Comment: you want me to post my cypress code which has other 25 validations?

Comment: Um, not sure - `Maximum call stack size exceeded` comes from a recursive function (usually) so would need to see that to help.

Comment: There's nothing recursing in the above code, so it's got to be in your flow methods.